# Existe algum jeito de saber se já fiz o git push?

Tags: git

Sempre quando preciso atualizar os repositórios, utilizo o comando `git push`.

O problema é que as vezes fico sem saber se já dei o pull ou não, por estar fazendo várias coisas ao mesmo tempo. Daí para descobrir se fiz o `git push` ou não, eu executo o `git push` novamente. Porém eu gostaria de um jeito mais eficiente de saber se já dei o `git push` nos commits que acabei de fazer, sem ter que fazer isso toda hora (afinal, tenho que ficar digitando usuário e senha).

Existe algum jeito mais rápido de se saber se eu já fiz o `push` das alterações pelo `Git`? Algo parecido com o `git status`?

Comment: Você usar o Git para Windows?

Comment: @DotNet não, uso o Linux (Ubuntu).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Há dua maneiras. A primeira é através da execução do git status, onde você terá uma mensagem como:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   app/app.iml

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Na segunda linha do retorno há algo como `Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'` que nos indica que o braço local `master` está atualizado em relação ao braço `origin/master`, que é o braço remoto. Ou seja, não há nada a trazer do braço remoto (`pull`), nem mesmo enviar para o braço remoto (`push`).

A segunda maneira é executando o próprio `git push` e verificando se algo novo foi enviado através da mensagem de feedback. Se for algo como `Everything up-to-date` significa que o push já foi realizado e não há nada mais a ser enviado.

Comment: A segunda maneira é a que não gosto. Valeu pela "primeira maneira"

Answer (score 3):

O `git status` vai te dizer se a sua *branch* local está atrasada ou adiantada em relação à origem. Se tiver adiantada (*ahead*), então quer dizer que você precisa `push` as suas atualizações.

No exemplo abaixo, eu fiz um commit local que ainda não foi *pushed* pra origem, então é preciso fazer o o `git push` se eu quiser mandar esse commit para a origem.

```
D:\mygit\myrepo>git status
On branch carlos_current
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/carlos_current' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Algumas notas:

- Você nem sempre precisa fazer o git push a cada commit. Um workflow bem comum no git é você fazer várias alterações (pequenas) localmente e depois push todas elas de uma vez, possivelmente combinando (*squash*) as modificações em uma única
- Você pode usar um *git credential manager* para não ter que entrar a senha todas as vezes.

Answer (score 2):

Vou deixa isso aqui caso você queira criar um cache de senhas.

> Por que Git sempre pedindo a minha senha?

Se Git pede-lhe um nome de usuário e senha toda vez que você tenta interagir com GitHub, você provavelmente está usando o *clone URL HTTPS* para o seu repositório.

Usando uma URL remota HTTPS tem algumas vantagens: é mais fácil de configurar do que o SSH, e, geralmente, funciona através de firewalls estritas e proxies. No entanto, ele também solicita que você inserir suas credenciais GitHub cada vez que você fizer pull ou push em um repositório.

Você pode configurar o Git para armazenar sua senha para você.

*Se você gostaria de configurar isso, siga os passos abaixo;*

**Caching sua senha GitHub no Git**

Se você está [clonando repositórios GitHub usando HTTPS](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?anno=2&depth=1&hl=pt-BR&rurl=translate.google.com.br&sl=en&tl=pt-BR&u=https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/&usg=ALkJrhgkIgk4dE5qUnD_BlkgKCws73XI1w) , você pode usar um ajudante de credencial para dizer Git para lembrar seu nome de usuário e senha GitHub cada vez que fala com GitHub.

Se você clonando repositórios GitHub usando SSH, então você autenticar usando chaves SSH em vez de um nome de usuário e senha. Para ajudar a configurar uma conexão SSH, [consulte Gerando uma Chave SSH](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?anno=2&depth=1&hl=pt-BR&rurl=translate.google.com.br&sl=en&tl=pt-BR&u=https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/&usg=ALkJrhjAQ7_KuNyZNg9U5-9Bw6fyD75tpQ) .

> Dica: Você precisa Git 1.7.10 ou mais recente para usar o ajudante de
>   credencial.

O auxiliar de credencial está incluído no GitHub Desktop. O aplicativo também oferece um shell Git, assim você não vai precisar instalar e configurar o Git manualmente. Para mais informações, consulte " [Introdução ao GitHub área de trabalho](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?anno=2&depth=1&hl=pt-BR&rurl=translate.google.com.br&sl=en&tl=pt-BR&u=https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/getting-started/&usg=ALkJrhjwlNcUSsELJwi0j-xdg73-2ucCRA) ."

Se você preferir trabalhar com a linha de comando, você também pode instalar um escudo Git nativo, como [Git para Windows](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?anno=2&depth=1&hl=pt-BR&rurl=translate.google.com.br&sl=en&tl=pt-BR&u=https://git-for-windows.github.io/&usg=ALkJrhgZRftmfSxwdwqTm0PDAUDdap6Iow) . Com Git para Windows, executando o seguinte na linha de comando irá armazenar suas credenciais:

> git config --global credential.helper wincred

Comment: Obrigado pela opção de salvar a senha, mas não vou usar. Não creio que seja uma boa ideia nesse caso. Aqui na empresa usamos o bitbucket. Se eu saisse da empresa, a minha senha estaria fácil para alguém pegar.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, realmente, já usei em empresa assim, mas a conta que tinha no git era da própria empresa ai sem problema.

Comment: Eu até tinha criado uma conta "genérica", onde poderia usar esse usuário para fazer os push, mas daí não saberia quem fez o quê. Desistimos da ideia no final :D

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar `git log` para saber o histórico de commits.

O output será do commit mais recente para o mais antigo, juntamente com o SHA-1, nome e e-mail do autor, data do commit e a mensagem.

Exemplo de output

```
    commit ca82a6dff817ec66f44342007202690a93763949
Author: Scott Chacon <schacon@gee-mail.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 17 21:52:11 2008 -0700

    changed the version number

commit 085bb3bcb608e1e8451d4b2432f8ecbe6306e7e7
Author: Scott Chacon <schacon@gee-mail.com>
Date:   Sat Mar 15 16:40:33 2008 -0700

    removed unnecessary test

commit a11bef06a3f659402fe7563abf99ad00de2209e6
Author: Scott Chacon <schacon@gee-mail.com>
Date:   Sat Mar 15 10:31:28 2008 -0700

    first commit
```

A documentação pode ser encontrada [aqui](https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History)

Comment: Mas você concorda comigo que eu posso fazer o commit sem fazer o pull e mesmo assimo git log vai funcionar, não é ?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters tem razão.